# Prevent jumping with angular-animate on items floated left

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, angularjs-animation

I'm using angular-animate in conjunction with angular filter for hiding and showing ads in an unordered list. I have everything working correctly, but when the animation occurs, the list items are "jumping" abruptly. You can see what I mean here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Aw0va3ROghcLpxvR6pv0?p=preview

(Click one of the filter links or enter something in the search field.)

I understand why it's doing it - because the list items are floated left and once the in-between items are hidden, the remaining list items shift to fill the space. What I'm wondering is if there's any way to make the shifts smooth, so they animate into the new positions rather than abruptly jump?